# How to check using findall in text file using Python?

Tags: python

I wrote a function to extract a pattern from a file, but it didn't work right. Why?

My code in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29):

```
import re

f = open('quran_final.txt','r')
r = open('q.txt','w')
p = re.compile('ROOT:(?P<root>[^ "]+)')
for line in f:
    root = p.findall(line)
    if(root):
        for word in root:
        print word
    else:
        print ' '
```

I think the problem is in the "check", but how should I change it?

My text file sample:

```
f:CONJ+ POS:V IMPV ROOT:Akl 2MP  
POS:LOC LEM:Hayov ROOT:Hyv  
POS:V PERF ROOT:$yA 2MP  
POS:ADJ LEM:ragad ROOT:rgd M INDEF ACC  
wa+ POS:V IMPV ROOT:dxl 2MP  
Al+ POS:N LEM:baAb ROOT:bwb M ACC  
POS:N LEM:saAjid ROOT:sjd MP INDEF ACC  
wa+ POS:V IMPV ROOT:qwl 2MP  
POS:N LEM:HiT~ap ROOT:HTT F INDEF NOM  
POS:V IMPF ROOT:gfr 1MP MOOD:JUS  
POS:N LEM:xaTiy^_#ap ROOT:xTA P ACC PRON:2MP  
wa+ sa+ POS:V IMPF ROOT:zyd 1MP  
Al+ POS:N ACT PCPL (IV) LEM:muHosin ROOT:Hsn MP ACC  
f:REM+ POS:V PERF (II) ROOT:bdl 3MS  
POS:V PERF ROOT:Zlm 3MP  
POS:N LEM:qawol ROOT:qwl M INDEF ACC  
POS:REL LEM:{l~a*iY MS  
POS:V PERF PASS ROOT:qwl 3MS  
f:REM+ POS:V PERF (IV) ROOT:nzl 1MP  
POS:REL LEM:{l~a*iY MP  
POS:V PERF ROOT:Zlm 3MP  
POS:N LEM:rijoz ROOT:rjz M INDEF ACC  
Al+ POS:N LEM:samaA^' ROOT:smw F GEN  
POS:V PERF ROOT:kwn SP:kaAn 3MP  
POS:V IMPF ROOT:fsq 3MP  
POS:V PERF (X) ROOT:sqy 3MS
```

Comment: Have a crack at fixing your indentation first and consider posting the full traceback (your error message) straight after.

Comment: i'm asking if this check is right or false?

Comment: Can't tell - can't copy and paste it to my interpreter (without fixing errors) - don't have any sample data to run either...

Comment: bi+ POS:N LEM:{som ROOT:smw M GEN
POS:PN LEM:{ll~ah GEN
Al+ POS:ADJ LEM:r~aHoma`n ROOT:rHm MS GEN
Al+ POS:ADJ LEM:r~aHiym ROOT:rHm MS GEN
Al+ POS:N LEM:Hamod ROOT:Hmd M NOM
l:P+ POS:PN LEM:{ll~ah GEN

Comment: this is some data from the file i want to extract the word after ROOT:

Comment: What does quarn_final.txt look like?

Comment: bi+ POS:N LEM:{som ROOT:smw M GEN
POS:PN LEM:{ll~ah GEN
Al+ POS:ADJ LEM:r~aHoma`n ROOT:rHm MS GEN
Al+ POS:ADJ LEM:r~aHiym ROOT:rHm MS GEN
Al+ POS:N LEM:Hamod ROOT:Hmd M NOM
l:P+ POS:PN LEM:{ll~ah GEN

Comment: what does it give you back when you run it, and what is the desired result?

Comment: my result should be for ex for line:POS:V PERF ROOT:$yA 2MP                 i want to get'$yA' but it didn't appear in the right position in the file it is shifted and in it's place there is space

Comment: Also you may want to post the sample text in the question, so we can tell where the newlines are.

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't appear in the right position in the file" your code that you gave doesn't write the results out to a file.

Comment: yes i print on the shell then take the result in a colum in excel sheet so when i checked it i found som shifts

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to include endline in your pattern

```
p = re.compile('ROOT:(?P<root>[^\s]+)')
```

Comment: Lol. After all the work of formatting the question, and asking for clarifications. You get the answer. :-/

Comment: what does the " add in the regex?

Comment: Hoopdady: ididn'tget the answer and i'm sorry for that

Comment: i think " not do any thing

Answer (score -2):

Indentation - print word needs to be indented another four spaces. root should be:

```
root = re.findall(p, line)
```